# Toggling colour mode when using React Context and MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to toggle between dark and light modes using a custom palette with MaterialUI, however I am getting some Type errors on the value and theme props for the context provider and theme provider respectively.

```
// theme.ts
export const ColorModeContext = React.createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
});

export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<'light' | 'dark'>('light');

  const colorMode = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) =>
          prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
        );
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [colorMode, theme];
};
```

```
// app.tsx
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { useMode, ColorModeContext } from './assets/theme/theme';

function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();
  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">Hello, World!</div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get the following errors from this code:

```
Type '{ toggleColorMode: () => void; } | Theme' is not assignable to type '{ toggleColorMode: () => void; }'.
  Property 'toggleColorMode' is missing in type 'Theme' but required in type '{ toggleColorMode: () => void; }'.
```

```
Type '{ toggleColorMode: () => void; } | Theme' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ toggleColorMode: () => void; }> | ((outerTheme: { toggleColorMode: () => void; }) => { toggleColorMode: () => void; })'.
  Type 'Theme' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ toggleColorMode: () => void; }> | ((outerTheme: { toggleColorMode: () => void; }) => { toggleColorMode: () => void; })'.
```

I have gone through the MaterialUI docs on this and googled but can't quite seem to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can see your `useMode` type, it will look like.

```js
(alias) useMode(): ({
    toggleColorMode: () => void;
} | Theme)[]
```

Below is a simple example.

```js
const app = [1, 2, 'hello'] // type: const app: (string | number)[]
```

Typescript can't assert your value type in array. So you should make typescript know the sequence type of array.

In this situation, you can use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```js
const app = [1, 2, 'hello'] as const // type: const app: readonly [1, 2, "hello"]
```

```js
export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<'light' | 'dark'>('light');

  const colorMode = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) =>
          prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
        );
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [colorMode, theme] as const; // this should solve your problem.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//theme.ts
export const useMode = () => {
...
    return {
        theme,
        colorMode
    };
}

//app.tsx
function App() {
    const { theme, colorMode } = useMode();
    ...
}
```

objects destructuring, not array destructuring.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).